# Matching against Value Classes in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, value-class

I've created the `Value Class`

```
final class Feature(val value: Vector[Double]) extends AnyVal
```

To `match` against that class in `scala`:

```
val d = new Feature(Vector(1.1))
s match {
  case a:Feature => println(s"a:feature, $a")
  case _ => println("_")
}
```

This works correctly, but in `Akka`, with the same class above, in the `receive` method this is not working:

```
  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case a:Feature =>
      log.info("Got Feature: {}", a)
    case _ => println("_")
  }
```

When I execute the code, although I am sending a `Feature`, the `case` statement that is being executed is `case _ => println("_")`, but, If I change the code to this:

```
  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case a:Feature =>
      log.info("Got Feature: {}", a)
    case b:Vector[_] =>
      log.info("GOT FEATURE")
    case _ => println("_")
  }
```

`case b:Vector[_]` is executed.

Akka documentation mentions:

> The recommended way to instantiate actor props uses reflection at runtime to determine the correct actor construc-
>   tor to be invoked and due to technical limitations is not supported when said constructor takes arguments that are
>   value classes. In these cases you should either unpack the arguments or create the props by calling the constructor
>   manually:

But do not mention nothing about matching against `Value classes`

## Update

Thanks to YuvalItzchakov for the help. The Actor's code is as below:

### Actor that receive the message:

```
  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case Feature(a) =>
      log.info("Got feature {}", a)
    // ....
  }
```

### Actor sending the message:

```
  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    // ..
    case json: JValue =>
      log.info("Getting json response, computing features...")
      val features = Feature(FeatureExtractor.getFeatures(json))
      log.debug(s"Features: $features")
      featureListener.get ! features
    // ..
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the nature of how value classes work, both your examples will cause the allocation of `Feature`. Once due to run-time checking in your pattern matching example, and the other due to the signature of `receive` which requires `Any` as the input type.

As the [docs for Value Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#allocation-summary) specify (emphasis mine):

> ### Allocation Summary
>
> A value class is actually instantiated when:
>
> - a value class **is treated as another type**.
> - a value class is assigned to an array.
> - doing **runtime type tests, such as pattern matching**.

This means that if you're seeing a `Vector[_]` type, that means your actually passing a concrete vector from some place in the code.

Comment: Thanks!, so, you recommend me to remove the Value class and  match against `Vector[Double]` ?

Comment: @algui91 I recommend not extending `AnyVal` and matching on `Feature`. Matching on higher kinded types is a bad idea since they're subject to type erasure and you always want to wrap them in an additional case class.

Comment: "you're sending Feature via tell to the actor, so the runtime doesn't allocate Feature" Why isn't this a case where "a value class is treated as another type", namely `Any`?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov You're completely right, I've overlooked the `Any` on `receive` and can't reproduce this locally. Looking at the generated Scala code the compiler still wraps the message with a `Feature`.